# Display json string to the table

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I get the following JSON String from server as response

```
{"json":[{"title":"Example Title 1","description":"Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac"},{"title":"Example Title 2","description":"Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac"}]}
```

Here is my code

```
<script>
  $("#getdata").on('click',function () {
  var form_data={       
                    agent_name: $('#agent_name').val(),
                    number: $('#number').val(),
                    quantity: $('#quantity').val(),
                    date: $('#date').val(),
                    commision: $('#commision').val(),
                    profit: $('#profit').val(),
                    agent_amount: $('#agent_amount').val(),
                    user_id: $('#user_id').val(),
                    type: name_type.val(),
                  }

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>admin_control/ajax_data',
    data: form_data,
    dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
    success: function(data){ 
        if(data){
            var len = data.length;
            alert(len);
            var txt = "";
            if(len > 0){
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                    if(data[i].number && data[i].type){
                        txt += $('#table').append('<tr><td>data[i].type</td><td>data[i].number</td><td>data[i].quantity</td><td>data[i].amount</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="add_checkbox" name="layout" id="add_checkbox" value="1" checked></td></tr>');

                    }
                }
                if(txt != ""){

                    $("#table").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                }
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
return false;
 });
</script>
```

Now i want to map the result in to my table by doing this am getting an error like `undefined` while using alert in length of the data

Comment: The server response json that you have posted in your question does not match with the json that you are trying to access in your ajax success code. e.g. `data[i].quantity`. This `quantity` key does not exists in your json code. Please provide actual response or modify your ajax code according to response json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for an Object size you can use

```
Object.keys(data).length;
```

Here is code for the specifc object you've given in the example

```js
var data = {"json":[
 {"title":"Example Title 1","description":"Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac"},
  {"title":"Example Title 2","description":"Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac"}
]};

var fragment = '';

console.log('object length:', Object.keys(data).length);
console.log('array length', data.json.length)

for(var i=0; i < data.json.length; i++){
 fragment += '<tr><td>'+ data.json[i].title +'</td><td>'+ data.json[i].description +'</td></tr>'; 
}
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML = fragment;
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: still the table is not getting append and value is not showing

Comment: what do you mean with table?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse data to JSON then manipulate it.

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data.length);
```

Comment: still the table is not getting append and value is not showing

Comment: Does this line `console.log(data.length);` show anything in console ?

Comment: i got like this `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`